# Question calculating the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n\theta}{n}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to calculate the value of the sum:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n\theta}{n}$$
I considered the disc $D(0,1)$ (open), and if $x\in D(0,1)$ 
then:
$$-\log(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n}\qquad$$

And I made the change, $x=e^{i\theta}$ in order to reach the $\sin(n\theta)$

$$-\log(1-e^{i\theta})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{in\theta}}{n}$$

So that:

$$\text{Im}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{in\theta}}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n\theta}{n}$$
My question is, do i have to test what happens in $\overline{D}(0,1)$ (closed) in order to make the change $x=e^{i\theta}$? Why? Thanks in advance!

Edit: I'm not sure of that, but I think if i make $\theta \in (0,2 \pi)$ then there are points of the closed disk that can be reached.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to test the *convergence* of the series (which is done using [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test)). The rest, if viewed as $x=re^{i\theta}$ with $r\to1^-$, is done by [Abel's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem) on power series.